# Postfix mailbox for an existing user

Tags: linux, postfix

For some strange reason, I just noticed my local user account on a box does not have a mail file in /var/mail.  I ran

```
touch /var/mail/username
```

To try and correct the issue but postfix is still not writing out information to that file.  Further I tried to send myself a message locally but did not go through.

Without recreating the user account, is there a way to get postfix to recognize the user?

Answer (score 2):

Don't touch a /var/mail/username if it's not there.  You'll probably get the permissions wrong.  Remove the file now, and then send that user an email.  Watch /var/log/mail.log to see what happens to it.

Answer (score 0):

It's entirely possible that the mail server is setup to deliver mail to some other location, such as a maildir or mbox file in the user's home directory.  As Paul recommended, look in the mail log to see what happens to incoming mail.  If it talks about being handed off to procmail, then check `~/.procmailrc` and `/etc/procmailrc` to see where mail gets delivered to.

Comment: And you might find procmail logging in ~/Mail/log for the user.